# How to save some pictures into one image?

Tags: wxwidgets

I draw some pictures with wxStaticbitmap in wxPanel.
And now I want to save these pictures into one file, better to be image format.
Is there any function I can call? Or how to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take a screenshot of the window containing the bitmaps.

Here is some detailed code showing how to do this - it is the second article down.

http://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?p=32313

Comment: Thanks for ur advice, but when I scroll the window, I have to take another screenshot again. This may cause some confusion of the pictures.